# Rails 5: update action not working for AJAXified form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have view with dropdown where on user select, particular user role can be edited.

In */common/roles/index.erb* I have this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="get" action="/common/roles" data-remote="true">
<div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control m-b" name="users" id="user_list">
  <option value="">Please, select user</option>
     <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <% for role in user.roles %>
           <option value="<%= role.id %>"><%= user.name %></option>
        <% end %>
     <% end %>
  </select>
</div>
</form>
<!-- Here we render role edit form -->
<div id = 'selected_role' ></div>
<!-- Role edit form ends -->
```

This is select where User names are displayed, role ID are option value.

In *roles.js* I have listener where on select role ID is passed for Edit:

```
(function($) {
$('#user_list').change(function() {
  var roleId = $( "#user_list" ).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: '/common/roles/' + roleId + '/edit',
    method: 'GET',
  });
});
})(jQuery); /*global jQuery*/
```

*/common/roles/edit.js.erb* looks like this:

```
$("#selected_role").html("<%=j render 'common/roles/editrole', locals: { role: @role } %>");
```

and it renders role edit partial */common/roles/_editrole.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for :role, method: :patch, remote: true do |f| %>
<form class="m-t" role="form" action="" id="editrole">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">General</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10" >
           <%= f.select :general, Role.generals.to_a.map { |w| [w[0].humanize, w[0]] }, {}, {class:"form-control m-b"} %>
            </div>
        </div>
   <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" %>
  <% end %>
</form>
```

To complete this form I still need to finish with Update action where I have problem. **On submitting role edit form it starts PATCH but with Edit url.** Here's error in console:

```
Started PATCH "/common/roles/1/edit"
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [PATCH] "/common/roles/1/edit"):
```

although particular PATCH route is in place:

```
common_role PATCH  /common/roles/:id(.:format)     common/roles#update
```

In */common/roles_controller.rb* I have this:

```
def update
@role = Role.find(params[:id])
if @role.update_attributes(role_params)
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
              flash[:success] = "Role updated!"
              redirect_to common_roles_path
  }
  format.js
```

In */common/roles/update.js.erb* I have this line: `$('.editrole').hide()`

I can open form in Edit and untill Update action it works fine.
**How do I fix Update action error, please?**

---

**Update for solution**

In Update action I was missing `respond_to do |format|` + */common/roles/update.js.erb* I had to change to this:

```
$('.container').empty().append('<%=
  escape_javascript(
    render 'update'
  )
%>')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
<%= form_for role, url: common_role_path(role), method: :patch, remote: true do |f| %>
```

`role` here refers to the local variable you passed while rendering the partial.

Comment: Thank you, this gives error: `ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `role'` and Edit form is not loading. However if I do `<%= form_for @role, url: common_role_path(@role), method: :patch, remote: true do |f| %>` it starts PATCH with correct url, but gives this error: `Completed 500 Internal Server Error` It's close to solution, but not yet... what can be wrong?

Comment: + error follow with these few more lines:
`ArgumentError (too few arguments):`
`app/controllers/common/roles_controller.rb:54:in format`
`app/controllers/common/roles_controller.rb:54:in update`

Comment: You're passing `@role` in the local variable `role` right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. It looks like I have problem in controller's Update action where I have format.html. It asks for different arguments there. Basically I want after role update to go back to index and flash success that role was updated.

Comment: @matiss You need to add `format.js` which will look for `update.js.erb` by default. Create `update.js.erb` and add a javascript response in there

Comment: I have `update.js.erb` with this inside `$('.editrole').hide()` I believe my code is a bit naive :) Can you help, please?

Comment: I'm a bit of idiot :) Forgot to add `repond_to |format|` Now it seems to be working and I have to take care of success flash now. Thank you for helping me.